# Is const initializer not guaranteed synchronous?

Tags: c++

If I compile with `g++ -O3` (other optimization flags work fine) the constructor initializer does not always init the variable before the `printf()`(at least it looks like this for me). My guess is that it's getting somehow parallelized by the compiler, because if I insert or remove marked lines I am getting consistently good results. If the code is working for you, try running it multiple times(`-O3` and `g++.exe (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0`).

As requested here is the original code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct dataset
{
    struct sample
    {
        float* const x;
        float* const y;

        sample(const int inputSize, const int outputSize) : x(new float[inputSize]), y(new float[outputSize])
        {
        }
        sample(float* const inputs, float* const outputs) : x(inputs), y(outputs)
        {
        }

        void clear()
        {
            delete[] x;
            delete[] y;
        }
    };

private:
    sample* samples = nullptr;
    int sampleCount = 0;
    const bool manageMemory;

public:
    const int xsize;
    const int ysize;

    dataset(const int inputSize, const int outputSize, const int reserved)
        : xsize(inputSize), ysize(outputSize), manageMemory(true)
    {
        // printf("%i == %i\n", xsize, inputSize); // <-- when I insert this line it works fine
        reserve(reserved);
    }
    dataset(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& inputs, const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& outputs)
        : dataset((int)inputs[0].size(), (int)outputs[0].size(), (int)inputs.size()) // std::vector could be the problem
    {
        if (inputs.size() != outputs.size())
        {
            printf("--- error: inputs and outputs are not equal size ---\n");
            return;
        }

        printf("%i | %i | %i\n", (int)inputs[0].size(), (int)outputs[0].size(), (int)inputs.size());
        printf("%i | %i | %i\n", xsize, ysize, sampleCount);
    }
    ~dataset()
    {
        if (manageMemory)
        {
            if (samples != nullptr)
            {
                printf("deleting\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
                {
                    samples[i].clear();
                }
                free(samples);
            }
        }
    }

    void reserve(const int reserved)
    {
        this->~dataset(); // <-- when removing this line it works

        sampleCount = reserved;
        samples = (sample*)malloc(sampleCount * sizeof(sample));

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
        {
            new (&samples[i]) sample(xsize, ysize);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    printf("A\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> inputs = { {1.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f, 1.0f} };
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> outputs = { {0.0f, 1.0f}, { 1.0f, 0.0f } };
    dataset data(inputs, outputs);
    printf("B\n");

    // output:
    // A
    // 2 | 2 | 2
    // 1186659328 | 32766 | 2
    // B
    // deleting

    // output (with extra printf):
    // A
    // 2 == 2
    // 2 | 2 | 2
    // 2 | 2 | 2
    // B
    // deleting
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4cY8dWxj9) Is this the exact code your're using? What's your `g++ --version`?

Comment: I will edit it now and I will use the exact code then it's actually not that long either

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If like to you can take a second look

Comment: @user17732522 If like to you can take a second look

Comment: @deanqx I mean, you literally write it yourself `this->~dataset(); // <-- when removing this line it works`.

Comment: You have destroyed your object and are hoping to get sensible data from it.

Comment: FYI, destructor is more than just code you have written in it. Calling it also has a lot of implication for object state and lifetime.

Comment: but why is `samples` not equals `nullptr`

Comment: Once you've invoked undefined behavior, the only answer to "why" anything is "because you've invoked undefined behavior, so the program is considered invalid and can do whatever it wants".   Pretty much the entire concept of undefined behavior is a way to allow compiler writers to not have to worry about what their compiler does in cases where the user broke the rules :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructors are special. They are not normal member functions. In particular they end the lifetime of the object on which they are called.

Once you have ended the lifetime of an object you are not allowed to refer to that object or use pointers/glvalues to that object any more, except in very narrow ways that are not applying here.

But, after you call `this->~dataset();` and end the lifetime of `*this`, you immediately try to assign to its members. Accessing a member outside the lifetime of the object is undefined behavior.

If you need to reset the state of the object, then move the contents of the destructor to a normal member function and call that function in the destructor and in the `reserve` function instead of relying on the destructor itself.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks, I will create a clear() function now